# Change the range on the horizontal axis of a google visualization linechart

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-visualization

I have a google visualization linechart that is attached to a button. When the button is clicked, the charts range and datavalues change to a different data array (you can see this in the code below).

However, on the last dataset (years) the range is crazy looking if there is only one year value in the dataset.

[image: Bad range for years]

So far, I've tried changing values in the main options declaration using hAxis minValue and maxValue but that results in an error. I've also tried changing the value on the fly through the button like I do with the chart title. That doesn't throw an error but it also doesn't work. I'm not sure what to try next.

Code:

```
  var options = {
    vAxis: {title: "Usage" },
    hAxis: {title: "Time" },
    animation:{
      duration: 1000,
      easing: 'out'
    }
  };

  var current = 0;
  var chart_title = 'Usage by Day';
  // Create and draw the visualization.
  var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('example2-visualization'));
  var button = document.getElementById('b1');
  function drawChart() {
     // Disabling the button while the chart is drawing.
    button.disabled = true;
    google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready',
        function() {
          if(current == 0){
                 button.innerHTML = 'Switch to Week';
                 chart_title = 'Usage by Week';
                 csv_element.href = link_usage_day;
                 usage_average_text.innerHTML = "You use a daily average of {{ calc_days_avg }} containers of {{ container }} ";
          }
         else if(current == 1){
                 button.innerHTML = 'Switch to Month';
                 chart_title = 'Usage by Month';
                 csv_element.href = link_usage_week;
                 usage_average_text.innerHTML = "You use a weekly average of {{ calc_weeks_avg }} containers of {{ container }}";
          }
          else if(current == 2){
                 button.innerHTML = 'Switch to Year';
                 chart_title = 'Usage by Year';
                 csv_element.href = link_usage_month;
                 usage_average_text.innerHTML = "You use a monthly average of {{ calc_months_avg }} containers of {{ container }}";
          }
          else if(current == 3){
                 button.innerHTML = 'Switch to Day';
                 chart_title = 'Usage by Day';
                 csv_element.href = link_usage_year;
                 usage_average_text.innerHTML = "You use a yearly average of {{ calc_years_avg }} containers of {{ container }}";
          } 
        });
    options['title'] = chart_title;    

    chart.draw(dataholder[current], options);
    button.disabled = false;
  }
  drawChart();

  button.onclick = function() {
    current = current + 1;
    if(current == 4) current = 0;
    drawChart();
  }
}
```

Comment: have you tried `hAxis.viewWindowMode: 'pretty'`?

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/customizing_axes) are some of the docs on axis customization for google visualization.  Also, make sure you're sending that date data as a datetime and NOT as utc or an int or anything.

```
    data.addColumn('datetime');
    data.addColumn('number');

    $.each(res.list, (k,v) => {
      data.addRow([new Date(v.dt_txt), v.main.temp]);
    });
```

Comment: Thanks, I ended up having to change the date data to a datetime and not an int like you said. I wanted to have year be an integer so I could represent it as just a number, but its much easier to treat it like a datetime then customize the axis to only show a number